# How to check if the first letter of URL is less than G?

Tags: php, url, if-statement

I am looking to echo a list of links based on the URL of a website. I was wondering if you could create an if/else to echo different lists based on the first letter of the domain of a site. So basically, if the domain starts with any letter before G, it would echo my first list, and if it is any letter after G, it would echo something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = "glue";
if ($str < "g"){
    //do stuff
    echo("yup");
}

$str = "fluor";
if ($str < "g"){
    //do stuff
    echo("yup2");
}
```

for your case

```
<?php 
$url = parse_url($_GET['url']); 
$str = $url['host']; 
echo $str; 
if ($str < "g"){ 
    //do stuff 
    echo(" has first character lower than g"); 
} 
else{ 
     echo(" has not first character lower than g"); 
}
```

- http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/99426.php?url=http://gamingcreation.org
- http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/99426.php?url=http://famingcreation.org

Comment: Shouldnt you use PHP ord Function to get the ASCII Code from the letter for compare them?

Comment: @genesis: Your solution does not work with strings starting with an uppercase letter. See: http://ideone.com/u19fg

Comment: @genesis how would I get the value from a URL to be the string?

Comment: @scube: who uses uppercase for url ?

Comment: @genesis: yes sort of, what I wanna do is grab the first letter of the domain and check it to see if it is less than "G" so to say

Answer (score 0):

just an idea:

```
$range_array = range('A','F');

if(in_array($foo,$range_array){
...
}
```

Comment: could I throw in a $SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] somewhere so that it could check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $url = "http://www.gaa.com";
    $parseURL = parse_url($url);
    $host = str_replace("www.","", $parseURL['host']);
    if($host[0] <= "g") {
        //do something.. 
    }else {
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a character to its ascii-value using `ord()`:

```
<?php 
    $ascii_value = ord($link[0]);
    if( $ascii_value >= 65 && $ascii_value < 72 ) echo 'Foo'; 
    else echo 'Bar'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My RegEx solution:

```
/^[a-f].*/gim
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$firstLetter = substr(strtoupper($your_url), 0, 1);
if(ord($firstLetter) >= 65 && ord($firstLetter) <= 71) {
    // ... first letter is an A, B, C etc. including G
}
else if (ord($firstLetter) >= 72 && ord($firstLetter) <= 90) {
    // ... first letter is H or a later character
}
else {
    // ... first letter is not a letter of the alphabet
}
?>
```